# How to obtain the input devices of a machine using a Python script?

Tags: python

I need help creating a Python program that retrieves a list of available microphones on my computer using Windows 10.

My code:

```
import pyaudio
import logging
import customtkinter as ctk
from pathlib import Path

def choisir_microphone():
    """
    Choisissez un micro disponible sur l'ordinateur.

    Returns:
        int or None: Index du microphone sélectionné, ou None si aucun microphone n'a été sélectionné.
    """
    
    # Obtenez le chemin du répertoire parent du fichier en cours d'exécution
    parent_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
    parent_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    # Définir le chemin complet du fichier de journalisation
    DIR_logs = parent_dir / "logs_micro.log"

    # Configuration du module de journalisation
    logging.basicConfig(filename=DIR_logs, level=logging.INFO, format='%(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    with open(DIR_logs, "w") as log:
        log.write("")

    def obtenir_microphones_disponibles():
        """
        Obtenez les microphones disponibles sur l'ordinateur.

        Returns:
            list: Liste des microphones disponibles, sous forme de tuples (index, nom).
        """
        try:
            audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
            microphones = []
            device_names = {}  # Dictionnaire pour stocker les noms des périphériques

            for i in range(audio.get_device_count()):
                device_info = audio.get_device_info_by_index(i)
                max_input_channels = device_info.get('maxInputChannels')

                if isinstance(max_input_channels, int) and max_input_channels > 0:
                    device_name = device_info.get('name')
                    # Vérifier si le périphérique a déjà été ajouté
                    if device_name not in device_names:
                        # Vérifier si le périphérique est un microphone
                        if 'microphone' in str(device_name).lower():
                            microphones.append((i, device_name))
                            device_names[device_name] = True
                    else:
                        logging.warning(f"Périphérique déjà existant : {device_name}")

            logging.info("Microphones disponibles et utilisables:")
            for index, microphone in microphones:
                logging.info(f"{index}: {microphone}")
                print(f"{index}: {microphone}")
                print("-" * 50)

            audio.terminate()
            return microphones

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Une erreur s'est produite : {e}")
            return []

    # Obtention des microphones disponibles
    microphones = obtenir_microphones_disponibles()

    if not microphones:
        logging.error("Aucun microphone disponible.")
        print("Aucun microphone disponible.")
        return None

    app = ctk.CTk()
    app.title('Choix du microphone')
    app.geometry("550x100")  # Taille de la fenêtre
    app.iconbitmap(parent_dir/"logo.ico")

    label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text="Choisissez un microphone:", font=("Arial", 14))  # Police réduite
    label.pack()

    microphone_choisi = None
    fenetre_fermee_sans_selection = False

    def callback_optionmenu(choix):
        nonlocal microphone_choisi
        nonlocal microphones
        index_microphone = [microphone[1] for microphone in microphones].index(choix)
        microphone_choisi = microphones[index_microphone][0]
        print("Microphone choisi (index):", microphone_choisi)
        app.destroy()  # Fermer la fenêtre quand un choix est fait

    def sur_fermeture_fenetre():
        nonlocal fenetre_fermee_sans_selection
        fenetre_fermee_sans_selection = True
        app.destroy()

    optionmenu_var = ctk.StringVar(value=microphones[0][1])
    optionmenu = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(app, values=[microphone[1] for microphone in microphones],
                                             command=callback_optionmenu,
                                             variable=optionmenu_var,
                                             font=("Arial", 14))  # Police réduite
    optionmenu.pack()

    app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", sur_fermeture_fenetre)
    app.mainloop()

    if fenetre_fermee_sans_selection:
        return None
    else:
        return microphone_choisi

if __name__ == "__main__":
    microphone_selectionne = choisir_microphone()
    print(microphone_selectionne)
```

Comment: I edited your question to keep only relevant information. A few problems: 1/ You don't give any debugging information. What *exactly* doesn't work with your current code? Include the complete error traceback if you get an error, or the actual vs expected output otherwise.

Comment: 2/ You say that you are a total beginner, but some parts of the code look surprising in this regard. Was this code written by ChatGPT or such?? 3/ You use modules which aren't part of the standard library for the GUI, so there is little chance that anyone will look for them and install them in order to try to run your code. You need to provide a [mre] with only the relevant part of the code. If you are a beginner, getting the relevant part to work with a text interface (and no logging and such) should be the **first** thing to do.

Comment: (And note that using French function and variable names really doesn't help people who don't speak French...)